# how to insert the lastInsertId in my custom database class after retrieving

Tags: php, mysql

how to insert the lastInsertId in php pdo mysql after retieving it.
i have achieved retrieving it from the database,
now i want to insert it have tried concatenating its not working not sure where the mistake is have tried many times not going anywhere but if i echo the lastinserted id its showing
Thank you in advance
this is my Code

```
public function addinvoice($data){

    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO tbl_invoce_total (sub_total,total_tax,total,last_activity)
                          VALUES (:sub_total,:total_tax,:total,:last_activity)');
    $this->db->bind(':sub_total',$data['sub_total']);
    $this->db->bind(':total_tax',$data['total_tax']);
    $this->db->bind(':total',$data['total']);
    $this->db->bind(':last_activity',$data['last_activity']);
    $this->db->execute();
    $lastserted_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    echo $lastserted_id;

    foreach ($data['productname'] as $key => $value) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_invoice_items (users_id,customer_id,companies_id,invoice_fk,productname,quantity,price,last_activity)
           VALUES (:users_id,:customer_id,:companies_id,$lastserted_id,:productname,:quantity,:price,:last_activity)");
        $this->db->bind(':users_id',$data['users_id']);
        $this->db->bind(':customer_id',$data['customer_id']);
        $this->db->bind(':companies_id',$data['companies_id']);
        $this->db->bind("$lastserted_id", 'invoice_fk');
        $this->db->bind(':productname',$data['productname'][$key]);
        $this->db->bind(':quantity',$data['quantity'][$key]);
        $this->db->bind(':price',$data['price'][$key]);
        $this->db->bind(':last_activity',$data['last_activity']);
        $this->db->execute();
    }

    echo $lastserted_id;
    die( print_r($data));
```

Comment: Come on,  how "$lastserted_id" even makes any sense? I mean, can't you *just* follow the example?

Comment: If you look at all the other placeholders in your query, they all start with a colon, so that's what your new placeholder needs to start with. And in every other `bind()` call, you provide the placeholder first, then the value, so that's what you need to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a placeholder into the SQL where you want the insertID to be substituted, then bind that placeholder.

You only need to create the prepared statement once. Then in the loop you bind the values and execute it.

```
public function addinvoice($data){

    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO tbl_invoce_total (sub_total,total_tax,total,last_activity)
                          VALUES (:sub_total,:total_tax,:total,:last_activity)');
    $this->db->bind(':sub_total',$data['sub_total']);
    $this->db->bind(':total_tax',$data['total_tax']);
    $this->db->bind(':total',$data['total']);
    $this->db->bind(':last_activity',$data['last_activity']);
    $this->db->execute();
    $lastserted_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    echo $lastserted_id;

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO tbl_invoice_items (users_id,customer_id,companies_id,invoice_fk,productname,quantity,price,last_activity)
           VALUES (:users_id,:customer_id,:companies_id,:invoice_fk,:productname,:quantity,:price,:last_activity)");
    foreach ($data['productname'] as $key => $value) {
        $this->db->bind(':users_id',$data['users_id']);
        $this->db->bind(':customer_id',$data['customer_id']);
        $this->db->bind(':companies_id',$data['companies_id']);
        $this->db->bind(':invoice_fk', $lastserted_id);
        $this->db->bind(':productname',$data['productname'][$key]);
        $this->db->bind(':quantity',$data['quantity'][$key]);
        $this->db->bind(':price',$data['price'][$key]);
        $this->db->bind(':last_activity',$data['last_activity']);
        $this->db->execute();
    }

    echo $lastserted_id;
    die( print_r($data));
```

Comment: Would you mind demostrating it using the placeholders

Comment: Have tried in the database there is nothing Happening would mind showing me the work out

Comment: I did demonstrate it using the placeholder. Don't you see `:invoice_fk` in the query?

Comment: You don't seem to be using standard PDO, since it uses `prepare()` and `bindParam()` -- `query()` is for executing non-prepared SQL. I made some guesses about how your API works.

Comment: it is using prepared statement from the database class  where it is been called from its looking like this     public function query($query){
            $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);     
    }

Comment: There's no built-in database class in PHP. So it's either homegrown or part of a third-party library.

Comment: There is a function have made in my database class to avoid using alot of codes in one place then i bind them from that side and the stmts are there as well

Comment: And I'm assuming that your `query()` is a wrapper for `prepare()`, and `bind()` is a wrapper for `bindParam()` or `bindValue()`. If that's correct, I think my code should work for you.

Comment: If it doesn't work as I wrote it, try moving the `query()` call inside the loop, like your version.

Comment: It has worked thank you so very much wow this is great